# Can Linear Discriminant Analysis be performed in Pyspark Python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I was trying to google dimensionality reduction techniques using Pyspark.

While I was able to find sources and articles on PCA , there was no articles for **Linear Discriminant Analysis**(if there they are very vague).

So, want to know if we have this functionality in Pyspark?

Comment: @andrew This is "Latent Dirichlet Allocation" and not "Linear Discriminant Analysis"

Comment: You're right, I deleted the link.

Comment: I don't think PySpark supports supervised dimension reduction.  You can use L1 regularization to reduce the feature space. Or you could locally train a LDA model on a down-sampled data set and then use the weight matrix to project the whole data set in PySpark.